# "resource(6, stream)" error when reading CSV

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file with the code below. When I call `var_dump`, I get the following response:

> resource(6, stream)

Can anyone help me with what is wrong with this code?

```
$file = fopen("other/papi.csv", "r");   
var_dump($file);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a resource.

if you want file contents you can use

```
var_dump(file_get_contents("other/papi.csv"))
```

if you want to read a CSV file use fopen and:

```
$file = fopen("fileName.csv","r");
while(!feof($file))
{
    $currentCsv = fgetcsv($file);
    var_dump($currentCsv);

}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

To read a csv you can use `fgetcsv`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php